# Replacing Text Using Regular Expression in Python With Named Parameters

Tags: python, regex, django

I have the string `"(r'^users/', include('users.urls')),"`. I want user to be able to change it to say `"(r'^users_part_has_been_changed_by_user/', include('users.urls')),"`

The regular expression is `'\s*[url]?\(r?["|\'](?P<pattern>[^\'"]+)["|\'],\s*include\(["|\'](?P<include>[^\'"]+)["|\']\)\),'`

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to change from the original to the changed version using regular expressions. I think it maybe `original.replace(re.search(the_expression, original).group('pattern'), new_pattern)`

Comment: You're looking for `re.sub()`. Did you write the expression yourself? Are you aware that `[]` denotes sets of letters, not substrings? Therefore `[url]` will match `u`, `r`, or `l`, not `"url"`.