# How to include overlength URLs in python comments

Tags: python, url, comments

When creating python code and keeping to the [PEP8 style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), one can have trouble to limit the line length to 79 characters when quoting a long URL in a comment:

```
def foo():
    # see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062540/replacing-text-using-regular-expression-in-python-with-named-parameters
    do_something()
```

In the actual code this looks ugly, when the URL comment overlaps with the otherwise empty indentation area on the left of the code. Is there some way to handle this in a better way, while I am still able to easily copy-and-paste the URL to put it into a web-browser?

Comment: I think url shortener is good solution for such cases. You can even find auto-shorteners for you editor (e.g. there are many ready-to-use solutions for emacs).

Comment: In the case of a StackOverflow link, SO will generate a short permalink url if you click on "share" below a question.  Since the URL is less descriptive, I find it useful to add more explanation about what the link is for in the comment surrounding the link.  Otherwise (for non-SO links), I think the best option is to suspend PEP8 and simply paste the long URL.  You could use a URL shortener, but that 1) removes useful information and 2) introduces an additional, unnecessary single point of failure (what's to say bit.ly or any other shortener will be around in 20 years?)

Answer (score 0):

Of the many possible way, use a \ at the end of line after closing the quotes

```
url = "http://stackoverflow" \
      ".com"

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print response.read()
```

In case you have a field such as url split on multiple lines and want easier way to copy it back, use multi line string i.e. surround your whole url with 3 double quotes on both start and end. Then they can span any number of lines.

Edit: I wrote multiline comments which was suggested in comments and has been fixed

Comment: Sure, when I want to use a URL within the code. But when I have a long URL just as comment, and I want to be able to just copy and paste is very easily (without putting URL parts together), then your approach will not work. See my updated question.

Comment: It wasn't clear earlier. I guess you can use multiline comments simply in that case i.e. " " " this is a multiline comment
which spawns many lines
like this
" " ""

Comment: That's not a multi-line *comment* but a multi-line *string*. Big difference!

Comment: Err yeah i guess he mentioned using it in context of comments so i wrote the term in flow. Will Edit. But it does serve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

### I'm using VS Code and you have 2 options:

1. hover on the link & get a pop-up with a link to press.
2. press 'option'+'click' on the URL at the comment itself.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

When you copy-and-paste from a mutli-line docstring, the browser will remove the spaces.

```py
class NewClass():
    def a_function():
        """
        For thanks and references, you can use a docstring.
        For example, "See this website:"

        Mock url: https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/#handling-docstring-
        indentation
        """
        pass
```